# Newrelic custom plugin metrics

Tags: newrelic-platform

I'm working directly with the HTTP API and trying to get some metrics from our storage.

The doc states "Tip: If you want the metric to appear as a percentage in the user interface, then you must define it as a percentage in the JSON."

However - I can't send metric values which are percentages; the POST response has status 400 with body

```
{"error":"Unable to parse request: null"}
```

My POST is

```
{"components": [
   {"duration": 1,
    "guid": "com.cumulus.Test5",
    "name":"ServerX",
    "metrics": {
      "Component/Filesystem/root/Percentage Used": "62%"
    }
   }],
 "agent": {"host": "vss-syd", "version": "1.0.0", "pid": 1080}
}
```

Also - I have a metric "Number of devices offline" (for a ZFS storage pool) which is discrete i.e. not continuous - so averages don't make sense, just absolute values.

For which I'd like to set an alert if it gets above 0.
I know the threshold is only 'greater than', so I can set thresholds @ 0.1 Alert & 0.2 Critical no prob.

However - please can someone point me in the right direction as to how I should

1. Send such a metric (i.e. need to specify [units] and aggregates?)
2. Create the Summary Metric + Graphs in the frontend? (which 'Value' to select e.g. 'Calls per minute')

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that look like they could be the cause.

The first is that the duration should be 60, which represents the number of seconds for which the reported metrics correspond. NewRelic is optimized to work with this particular interval and while you can have larger values (300 seconds is the recommended maximum), the minimum required value is 60. Smaller values may be accepted by the API, but the results will be unpredictable.

The second is that the percentage used is a string value which should instead be reported as an integer value, such as 62, or a float value of 62.0 if you wish to preserve that level of precision.

Regarding the second portion of your question about reporting and displaying a metric related to "# of Failing Disks":

New Relic does not currently support reporting metrics that represent absolute values. All metric values are presented in aggregate over some particular time period. Summary Metrics are aggregated over the most recent ~4 minutes, while metrics on charts and tables are aggregated over the time period selected in the time picker.

That said, you could try something along the lines of "percentage of failing disks" where perhaps an average might still be useful in that any non-zero value indicates a failure.

This average would be of questionable value once the aggregation time period became larger than a few minutes. However, given that summary metrics are always aggregated over a fixed time period of ~4 minutes — and it is summary metrics that trigger alerts — this may still be useful to you.

Comment: Thankee. My duration has been 60 most of the time. I guess my question is more on how to
1. Send and
2. Set Summary Metrics (and Chart),
for a metric such as "Number of failed Disks".
In the "Metric(s)" dropdown there doesn't seem to be a suitable choice like "Last Value".
Would "Calls per Minute" with 1 minute intervals do the trick?

Comment: Hi Randy, still can't figure this out, any advice?